# ODataModel and JSONModel have different Binding Contexts (sPath)

Tags: sapui5

When I bind an OData service directly on a table, the binding path looks like `/Customer('ALFKI')`.

When I read the OData into a JSONModel and bind the JSONModel to a table, the path looks like `/Customer/1`.

How can I make the JSONModel have the same look as the ODataModel?

Reading OData, and saving the results into the JSONModel "Customer"

```js
oODataModel.read("/" + sPath, {
  filters: aFilters,
  sorter: aSorter,
  success: function(oData, response) {
    console.log(oData.results);
    oControl.setModel(oModelJson, sJsonModel);
    oModelJson.setData({
      "Customer": oData.results
    });
  }
});
```

I could iterate the `oData.results` and create a key for each entry, like

```js
sPath = oODataModel.createKey("/" + "Customer", oContectObject);
```

.. but is there a better option to achieve this?

I looked into further OData binding examples, like [Addressing Entities: Binding Path Sytnax](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html#loioc4be40ce21ff4d0485b1d8f8114f7426).

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why JSONModel in the first place? What was missing from the ODataModel?

Comment: In this case, I am merging several data from different JSON Models into one. i later have to use the aggregated data on a table.